# Outer measure $u^*$ generated by $(\varepsilon, \rho)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be infinite and $f:X\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ an arbitrary function. Let $\varepsilon=\{\emptyset,X\}\bigcup\{\{x\}:x\in X\}$ and set$\rho(\emptyset)=0$, $\rho(X)=+\infty$ and $\rho(\{x\}):=f(x),\forall x\in X$. Carry out the construction of Caratheodory's theorem, i.e., describe the resulting outer measurr $u^*$ generated by $(\varepsilon,\rho)$ and the $\sigma$-algebra of $u^*$ measurable sets.

This is one question in my homework. I understand the proof of Caratheodory's theorem completely, but I am just confused by the question. I don't know what is being asked now. For example, do they want want me to prove that $\rho$ is a measure or outer measure already or do they want me to add more conditions such that $\rho$ will become an outer measure? In addition, what does "outer measure $u^*$ generated by $(\varepsilon,\rho)$" mean? I am not sure about what they are asking now. I hope someone can give me a hint or example to demonstrate what they are asking, because for me, I really don't think $\rho$ is an outer measure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, $\varepsilon\neq P(X)$. So we're requested to find an outer measure $u^*$ (defined on $P(X)$) such that $u^*|_\varepsilon=\rho$. Next, the question requests a descriptions of those subsets of $X$ which are $u^*$-measurable (this is a $\sigma$-algebra, containing $\varepsilon$, on which $u^*$ is a measure).

Comment: So, in the end, the sigma algebra generated by the outer measure will be the same as the smallest sigma algebra generated by the singleton set of $X$, which is $P(X)$(I mean in our case)

Comment: Well, not exactly; $\varepsilon$ is actually contained in a coarser $\sigma$-algebra.